# Usefulness of Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle

Tags: mathematics, nielsen-and-chuang

$
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left\langle#1\right|}
$The Heisenberg Uncertainty principle as formulated in Nielsen and Chuang is

$$
\Delta (C) \Delta (D) \geq \frac{|\bra{\psi}[C,D]\ket{\psi}|}{2}
$$

Later this is used in an example concerning $X$ and $Y$ when measured for the quantum state $\ket{0}$. It is stated that

$$
\Delta (X) \Delta (Y) \geq \bra{0}Z\ket{0} = 1
$$

My question is, what does this actually tell me? Knowing that the state being measured is $\ket{0}$, I can easily calculate the components of the left hand side exactly so whats the use of the inequality? Is it only useful for an unknown state for which we happen to know or can more easily calculate the right or left hand side?

Comment: Well, if you know the uncertainty for any state, you can find which state has the minimal uncertainty, then say (from this bound) that every other state must have more uncertainty than this minimal-uncertainty state - that might be a useful piece of information

Comment: Also practically, you can argue that doing one calculation on the right-hand side is less work than two on the left-hand side

Comment: Usually you are interested in finding states with the minimal uncertainty. If that is not the case, the uncertainty principle is just a neat formal to show that non-commuting observables cannot have a common basis, which is one of the weirdest things about quantum mechanics.